# Delete cascade always results in conflict with foreign key constraint

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, cascade

I currently have two different tables for storing different types of models (I'll call them `Task` and `Computer` for the purpose of this question).

When a new task is created, it is assigned a computer (which will be used for computing the task). After the task is finished, the computer can be used again for other tasks, and the task is marked as finish.

The `Task` model definition looks like this:

```py
class Task():
    __tablename__ = "task"
    id = Column(String(32), primary_key=True, default=lambda: uuid4().hex)
    creation_timestamp = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    computer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Computer.id))
    computer: Computer = relationship(Computer, cascade="all, delete-orphan", single_parent=True)
```

And the `Computer` model definition looks like this:

```py
class Computer():
    __tablename__ = "computer"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(32))
```

The problem is that after a task is finished, when trying to delete the computer that was used for the task, I'm getting the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation) update or delete on table "computer" violates foreign key constraint "task_computer_id_fkey" on table "task"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(100) is still referenced from table "task".
2019-09-23T14:31:19.358364700Z 
[SQL: DELETE FROM computer WHERE computer.id = %(id_1)s]
[parameters: {'id_1': '100'}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)
```

What I'd like to happen is that when the computer gets deleted, all of the previous tasks which used it will be deleted as well. From a look at [the documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/cascades.html#delete-orphan) it seems like the `all, delete-orphan` cascade should be enough for achieving this behavior, which is why I can't figure out why this is happening.

It would be great if you could help me understand why this is happening, and how to correctly configure things so that I'll get the desired behavior. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is it out of the question to put the FK on the computer table? It seems to me like you'd actually want that. That would represent 1 computer having many tasks. Currently you're representing the data as 1 task has many computers. Pretty sure your cascade delete would work that way too. Cascade deletes from the base to all descendants. So when you try to delete a computer from underneath task, it is complaining because it is dependent on that record to maintain the FK relationship. In short, you want the FK `task_id` on the computer table and define the relationship on `computer` for `task`.